# Batch - deleting files older than specific date with command input

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that deletes files older than a specified date from command/console input.
It needs to look in the subdirectories too.
Here is my code that doesn't seem to work.

```
    @echo off
echo This is the file deleter batch
echo You have to give it a specific date and the program will delete files older than that date
echo You have to give the date like this format: %date% 
set myDate=%date%
set myPath=%cd%
set /p inputDate=Give me the specific date:
forfiles /p "%myPath%" /s /m *.* /D -"%inputDate%" /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: Well if you create a `%myDate%` variable then use one named `%inputDate%`, it is unlikely to use the expanded content. Also there is no need to use the `/m` option, and your command should exclude directories, i.e. `if @isdir==FALSE`. As a side note, there is no need to create variables whose content is that of already existing variables, just use them directly instead. `@%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /D -%DATE% /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C If @IsDir==FALSE Del /A /F @Path"`. _(forfiles will alreadty use the current directory, if not provided)_

Comment: If you're not really using `%date%` and `%cd%`, then `@%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /P "%myPath%" /D -%myDate% /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C If @IsDir==FALSE Del /A /F @Path"`.

Comment: Thank you, yeah, I don't need the %myDate%, I'll delete it. I understand your reply, but I need a specific date from user, not the system date. I have to delete older files than the user's given date. :/

Comment: We need you to show us exactly what date format your target machine requires, `forfiles /?` should show you that, and the exact date format you or your end user is inputting at the prompt. Please note that your use of `set /p` is currently uncontrolled, your end user could enter nothing at all there, or anything they wanted, including deliberate or accidentallt malicious strings and characters. You cannot just tell us that your code doesn't work, you need to debug it, and [edit] your question to include the debugging information and all of the things we need to reproduce your reported issue.